# Why is Authorization Header missing?

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, microservices

I have Eureka and connected services **Zuul:8090**, **AuthService:[any_port]**.

I send ***../login*** request to Zuul he send to AuthSercice. Then AuthSerice put into Header JWT Authentication.

```java
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject( ((User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
            .compact();

    response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token); // this is missing
    response.addHeader("Authorization2", "Bearer " + token); // ok
}
```

I do request on Postman. [Request result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjMbu.png)

First I tried to use JWT in Monoliths. There wasn't any problem, and Authorization Token can be added.

**Why is Authorization Header missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of a built-in mechanism in Zuul  -- it automatically filters out sensitive headers, such as `Authorization` and `Cookies`, to protect sensitive information from being forwarded to downstream services.
  That is why you can not get the header with the name `Authorization`.

if you want your downstream services to receive them anyway, just define the filter by yourself in your Zuul config file, instead of using default.

```
 zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: your url pattern
      sensitiveHeaders: //put nothing here!! leave it blank, the filter will be off
      url: downstream url
```

Here is spring official explanation on sensitive headers: [document](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_cookies_and_sensitive_headers)

Answer (score 0):

You need set the option for forwarding headers in Eureka. 
For Login I would suggest to have a custom ZuulFilter.

```
public abstract class AuthenticationZuulFilter extends ZuulFilter {

private static final Log logger = getLog(AuthenticationZuulFilter.class);

private static final String BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE = "Bearer ";
private static final String PRE_ZUUL_FILTER_TYPE = "pre";

private AuthTokenProvider tokenProvider;

public AuthenticationZuulFilter(AuthTokenProvider tokenProvider) {
    this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
}

@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = getCurrentContext();
    ctx.addZuulRequestHeader(X_USER_INFO_HEADER_NAME, buildUserInfoHeaderFromAuthentication());
    ctx.addZuulRequestHeader(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE + tokenProvider.getToken());
    return null;
}

@Override
public String filterType() {
    return PRE_ZUUL_FILTER_TYPE;
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 1;
}
```

This is an implementation of it can be like this.

```
@Component
public class UserAuthenticationZuulFilter extends AuthenticationZuulFilter {

@Value("#{'${user.allowed.paths}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> allowedPathAntPatterns;

private PathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

@Autowired
public UserAuthenticationZuulFilter (AuthTokenProvider tokenProvider) {
    super(tokenProvider);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    Authentication auth = getContext().getAuthentication();
    HttpServletRequest request = getCurrentContext().getRequest();
    String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();
    String requestMethod = request.getMethod();
    return auth instanceof UserAuthenticationZuulFilter && GET.matches(requestMethod) && isAllowedPath(requestUri);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't understand why...
1. Why I need forward headers in Eureka? 
2. Actually I can use Another_Auth_Header. I can't get why is Authentication Header deleted.

Comment: Zuul acts like a proxy and the gateway is forwarding requests.
Have you tried my solution ?

Comment: I tried, but it becomes complicated a lot of o things I don't know. But I have to keep to go further, so I just use another token. Anyway thanks.